# How to use Requests.Get to produce a list of status codes for a large number of sites

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, seo

I'm a novice python programmer and I'm trying to use the requests library to find http status codes for a large list of urls, put those status codes into their own array, then add the status code array back to the dataframe as a new column.

Here's a very basic version of the code that I'm using.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

targets =pd.read_csv('/file/path.csv',header=None)
targetList =targets.values
for i in targetList:
    r = requests.get (f"{i}")
    r.status_code
```

I'm not concerned about the dataframe manipulation, that seems simple enough. And I can get the requests to work as discrete incidents

```
r=requests.get(targetList.item(0))
code=r.status_code
code

200
```

When I try to run the for loop however I get the following error.

`InvalidSchema: No connection adapaters were found for "['https://www.google.com']"`

Clearly the program is at least getting far enough to understand that the items in the list are strings, and understands the contents of those strings. But there's a disconnect happening that I don't understand.

Comment: It looks like your data may be stored incorrectly. Your URL is surrounded by square brackets and quotes, which the `requests` library isn't able to interpret.

Comment: `i` is list with all values in row (even if you have only one column) and you have to get single value from this row - ie. `i[0]`. But you should also check what you have in this column. Maybe you first created column with lists `[url]` instead of single `url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable `i` gives you list with all values in row - even if you have only one column - and you have to get single value from this list - ie. `i[0]`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'urls': ['url1','url2','url2'], 
} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
for row in df.values:
    url = row[0]
    #print('row:', f'{row}')
    #print('url:', f'{url}')
    print('row:', row)
    print('url:', url)

    #requests.get(url)

    print('---')
```

Result:

```
row: ['url1']
url: url1
---
row: ['url2']
url: url2
---
row: ['url2']
url: url2
---
```

Or you should select single column - `df['urls']`

```
for url in df['urls']:
    #print('url:', f'{url}')
    print('url:', url)

    #requests.get(url)

    print('---')
```

Result:

```
url: url1
---
url: url2
---
url: url2
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
targetList.item(0)[2:-2]
```

The following code reproduces your error for me:

```
import requests
u = "['https://www.google.com']"
r=requests.get(u)
code=r.status_code
code
```

and the following returns 200:

```
import requests
u = "['https://www.google.com']"
r=requests.get(u[2:-2])
code=r.status_code
code
```